# Modify Inline Angular Variable From Controller

Tags: angularjs

so I have this in my index.html:

```
 <!-- Nav -->
 <nav ng-init="cartempty=true" id="nav">
   <span ng-if="!cartempty">
     <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>: {{total}} 
   </span>
   <span ng-if="cartempty">
     <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>: Cart Empty 
     <i class="fa fa-frown-o"></i>
   </span>
 </nav>
```

When somebody adds to the cart, I want cartempty to go *false*.

I was trying to do this in the controller, off an `ng-click` that launches the `plusOne` function, but it wasn't working...

```
$scope.plusOne= function(theBread, theNumber) {
    cartempty = false;    
    function searchandreplace(nameKey, myArray){
    for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i].text === nameKey) {
            myArray[i].quantity = theNumber;
        }
    }
}
searchandreplace(theBread, $scope.BreadsToOrder)

}
```

Is it a scope issue? How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, it looks like a scope issue. Try to remove the `ng-init="cartempty=true"` from your `<nav>` in HTML and instead use `$scope.cartempty = true;` in your controller. Even if that doesn't work, [it's good practice to initialize variables in the controller rather than using ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit). (Also, like @csmithmaui said, make sure you use `$scope.cartempty = false;` rather than `cartempty = false;` in your `plusOne` function.)

If that works, it's probably because some directive (in between your controller and `<nav>`) is creating a new child scope. So then `<nav ng-init="cartempty=true">` puts `cartempty` on the child scope, so your `span`s never see `cartempty` on the *parent* scope set by the controller. For more info, see: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes.

By the way, it's also good practice to use the ["controller as" syntax](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) to avoid scope issues like this.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In the `ng-if` can I say `ng-if="cartempty"` or should it be `ng-if="$scope.cartempty"` or something? I'm trying to see if the problem is here too, although I will read up on those links you posted to try and get the answer.

Comment: Using `ng-if="cartempty"` is fine. The only time you need to use `$scope.cartempty` is in the controller.

Comment: One last thing you can try is `ng-init="$parent.cartempty=true"` (i.e., add `$parent.` to the front of `cartempty`). I didn't mention it before because it's considered bad practice to use `$parent`, but if it works, then use it. Other than that, I'm all out of ideas. =)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use `$scope.cartempty=false;` not just `cartempty=false;`

Comment: are you sure your function plusOne is getting called when you click on whatever element has the ng-click?  I do stuff like this all the time and it seems like it should work if that function is getting called.

Comment: yes, I tested with an alert and it is definitely getting called.

Comment: check this out...it's working for me. http://embed.plnkr.co/ZT16bWqsAggLiRCgNOki/preview also, check your console for errors and make sure you use $scope if you are working in the controller

Comment: no console errors, still not working in my implementation... I will keep trying.